Не перезаписывается URL при смене категорий (taxonomies) у записи (custom_post_type) - Wordpress
Вставил код с WP-KAMA (регистрация таксономии и постов с префиксом в ЧПУ у таксономии как и у типа записи).
Всё отлично работает. Но у меня проблема.
После перезаписи ЧПУ в админке, перестаёт меняться(перезаписываться) URL при смене категорий к посту.
Структура ЧПУ произвольо - /%category%/%postname%/
Пример:
Публикую (CPT) запись - у неё по умолчанию URL http://...faq/no-faqcat/kak-tak/
(no-faqcat - категория по умолчанию)
Назначаю ей категорию (taxonomies) "Рубин". Обновляю в браузере страницу поста (где вывод постов). В самой странице хлебные крошки изменились (появилась категория "Рубин") а URL страницы остался таким же http://...faq/no-faqcat/kak-tak/ (без новой назначенной категории "Рубин").
В админке адрес поменялся и при нажатии "посмотреть запись" переходим на
http://.../faq/rubin/kak-tak/ но при этом, осталась страница с URL с "no-faqcat"
Помогите пожалуйста. Что и куда надо добавить - прописать?
    add_action( 'init', 'register_faq_post_type' );
            add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'faq_permalink', 1, 2 );

            function register_faq_post_type() {
            register_taxonomy( 'faqcat', [ 'faq' ], [
            'label'                 => 'Раздел вопроса',
            'labels'                => array(
            'name'              => 'Разделы вопросов',
            'singular_name'     => 'Раздел вопроса',
            'search_items'      => 'Искать Раздел вопроса',
            'all_items'         => 'Все Разделы вопросов',
            'parent_item'       => 'Родит. раздел вопроса',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Родит. раздел вопроса:',
            'edit_item'         => 'Ред. Раздел вопроса',
            'update_item'       => 'Обновить Раздел вопроса',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить Раздел вопроса',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Новый Раздел вопроса',
            'menu_name'         => 'Раздел вопроса',
            ),
            'description'           => 'Рубрики для раздела вопросов',
            'public'                => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => false, // равен аргументу public
            'show_ui'               => true, // равен аргументу public
            'show_tagcloud'         => false, // равен аргументу show_ui
            'hierarchical'          => true,
            'rewrite'               => array('slug'=>'faq', 'hierarchical'=>false, 'with_front'=>false, 'feed'=>false ),
            'show_admin_column'     => true,
            ] );


            register_post_type( 'faq', [
            'label'               => 'Вопросы',
            'labels'              => array(
            'name'          => 'Вопросы',
            'singular_name' => 'Вопрос',
            'menu_name'     => 'Архив вопросов',
            'all_items'     => 'Все вопросы',
            'add_new'       => 'Добавить вопрос',
            'add_new_item'  => 'Добавить новый вопрос',
            'edit'          => 'Редактировать',
            'edit_item'     => 'Редактировать вопрос',
            'new_item'      => 'Новый вопрос',
            ),
            'description'         => '',
            'public'              => true,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_rest'        => false,
            'rest_base'           => '',
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'capability_type'     => 'post',
            'map_meta_cap'        => true,
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'rewrite'             => array( 'slug'=>'faq/%faqcat%', 'with_front'=>false, 'pages'=>false, 'feeds'=>false, 'feed'=>false ),
            'has_archive'         => 'faq',
            'query_var'           => true,
            'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'faqcat' ),
            ] );

            }

            function faq_permalink( $permalink, $post ){

            // выходим если это не наш тип записи: без холдера %faqcat%
            if( strpos( $permalink, '%faqcat%' ) === false ){
            return $permalink;
            }

            // Получаем элементы таксы
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'faqcat' );
            // если есть элемент заменим холдер
            if( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ){
            $term_slug = array_pop( $terms )->slug;
            }
            // элемента нет, а должен быть...
            else {
            $term_slug = 'no-faqcat';
            }

            return str_replace( '%faqcat%', $term_slug, $permalink );
            }

